# Select2 Loading Remote Data Not Populating

Tags: jquery, json

I have seen several questions asked about this, but I still can't get my code to work and it is driving me crazy.  I am using the following JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#e2").select2({
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                ajax: {
                    url: "http://myjsonexample.com/json/",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function( term, page){
                        return {
                            q: term
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        return { results: data};
                    }
                },
            });
        });
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="e2" style="width:300px" />
```

http://myjsonexample.com/json/ returns static JSON (which is set to mime-type application/json):

```
{
        results: [
            {id:1, text:'Result 1'},
            {id:2, text:'Result 2'},
            {id:3, text:'Result 3'}
        ],
        more: false
}
```

I have tried to keep the whole thing as basic as possible.  I can see the File being returned when I type - but the drop down does not populate.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `console.log()` ?

Comment: Yes - I attached console.log to execute when the results function is fired and nothing happens. results: function (data, page) {
            console.log("call results");
      return { results: data};

Comment: Try using `Firebug` or `Chrome Inspector` to check if the url is being called at all. If it is, and returns OK, then try this on `results` function : `return { results: data.results };`

Comment: Hi - Yes, the URL is being returned and the JSON is correctly formatted.  It seems that the "results: function" isn't being fired for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the documentation for that plugin?

Comment: Here's what I have: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Documentation states in order to use ajax to populate the list, you must use a `<input type="hidden" />` instead of a `<select></select>`. Are you doing that? Please update your question with the respective markup.

Comment: Sorry - I've been away.  Here is my Mark-up: <input type="hidden" id="e2" style="width:300px" />

Comment: You haven't reported if `return { results: data.results };` worked. You must feed the plugin with a iterable array.

Comment: Actually - since I have been playing with the code that is exactly what I am doing, but it still doesn't work.  I have a `console.log("results call fired");` after `results: function (data, page) {` but it doesn't get called.  For some reason `results` does not fire.

Comment: It looks like the ajax call isn't being fired at all, can you confirm it? Are you fetching the data from a server you own or from an external source?